# Query to list all tables in Oracle NoSQL

Tags: oracle-nosql

I need to list down all user or system tables available in Oracle NoSQL Database.
Please help with query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Which language API are you using. If it is Python the answer is as follows: Let's assume that you have the handle, then the following function will do the job:

```py
def listTables(handle):
    try:
        print('Listing tables')
        ltr = ListTablesRequest()
        lrResult = handle.list_tables(ltr)
        print('Existing tables: ' + str(lrResult))
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        traceback.print_exc()
    finally:
        print("end table listing")
```

Comment: I am using Oracle NoSQL in Linux 7.9 and data is in json format.